# How do you get the current SynchronizationContext for a specific WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, synchronizationcontext

Ok, I'm a little confused here.  Going over code relating to the `SynchronzationContext`, specifically when used in WPF so it's actually a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`.  Below is an excerpt from MSDN Magazine about this class:

> DispatcherSynchronizationContext (WindowsBase.dll: System.Windows.Threading) WPF and Silverlight applications use a DispatcherSynchronizationContext, which queues delegates to the UI thread’s Dispatcher with “Normal” priority. ***This SynchronizationContext is installed as the current context when a thread begins its Dispatcher loop*** by calling Dispatcher.Run. The context for DispatcherSynchronizationContext is a single UI thread.
>
> All delegates queued to the DispatcherSynchronizationContext are executed one at a time by a specific UI thread in the order they were queued. The current implementation creates ***one DispatcherSynchronizationContext for each top-level window***, even if they all share the same underlying Dispatcher.

(From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

What confuses me is the two parts that I bolded/italicized seem to be in contradiction to one another.  The first seemingly says one `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` is created per thread and set as the thread's current sync context. However, the second excerpt says one `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` is created ***per window*** even if they all share the same dispatcher/UI thread.

What am I missing/not understanding?

And if it really is one per window, not just per thread, how do you get the `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` for a specific window?

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, the `SynchronizationContext` is essentially a wrapper for the Dispatcher. If you look at the implementation [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherSynchronizationContext.cs), you can see that the `Post` and `Send` methods wrap `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`.

What the documentation is referring to regarding the `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` is that it's grabbing the current UI thread to do the work, i.e., using

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

while, `SyncrhonizationContext` is actually using the current thread's dispatcher, regardless of whethere it is UI related or not.

```
Thread.CurrentContext
```

Since all Windows run on the UI thread, there is no way to get a specific `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` for each.

Comment: I understand that it wraps the dispatcher, but I'm wondering if that's the case, why would they create one for each window? What would be the point of that as opposed to just one per dispatcher?   And again, if there is one per window, which one gets put in the current property of the thread when the dispatcher starts as per the documentation I quoted? Is it just the first one created?

Answer (score 0):

All UI application ( like WinForms and WPF) have special UI thread (for current Window), and SynchronzationContext.Post ( that translate in case WPF - to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke) set sended delegate as parameter into the UI thread queue for current window. So - each Window have own SynchronzationContext, but in thread you can use different SynchronzationContext.

And one point more - each thread have ExecutionContext, but only UI threads have SynchronzationContext ( in other - for example from CLR ThredPool - SynchronzationContext=null). And when you capture context:

```
ExecutionContext ec = ExecutionContext.Capture();
```

inside ExecutionContext you will have SynchronzationContext, so

```
Thread.CurrentContext
```

it's about ExecutionContext , SynchronzationContext you can grab by

```
var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Comment: What is `Thread.CurrentContext`? Can you write what namespace the `Thread` comes from?  I found only `Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext`.